# Finding code changes that have not been reverted in GIT

Tags: git

I am trying to find all the commits in GIT that were not reverted later on.

i.e. Bob makes commit 1abc in branch feature/bobs_feature. He merges feature/bobs_feature into develop in commit 2def on 22nd Jan. That means on the 23rd Jan the code in from commit 1abc was in develop.

On the 25th Jan Steve makes commit 3def that reverts the merge of feature/bobs_feature from develop. He then makes a commit 4abc when he merges in the revert.

Now, this means the code changes from commit 1abc are no longer in develop.

if I run: git log   I will see all commits -> 1abc, 2def, 3def and 4abc

Even though there are 4 commits... the net effect is the code has not changed.

Is there a way to see that on the 23rd Jan, the changes from 1abc were in develop and not reverted? Likewise on the the 25th Jan there were no commits whose changes were still applied to develop?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?